# Having issues with adding two positions of array

Tags: multidimensional-array

Question in regards to adding arrays. I have this code below:

B[row][col] = B[row+1][col+1] + B[row][col+1];

Let say row = 2, col = 3;  I don't quite understand what happens how.  We have the (=) assignment so I'm guessing would assign whatever is on the right but I don't know how to count it.  In this example it come up to me to be: 13 on the right side but that doesn't make sense. I would assign 13 value to b[row][col] ???  In the tracing program showed as 2. I don't understand, please help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what it is you're asking but essentially you have a 2D array and the B[row][col] syntax is to access a specific "cell" within the 2D array. Think of it like a grid. So what you're doing with the assignment operator is taking the values in cells B[row+1][col+1] and B[row][col+1], adding them together, and assigning that resulting value to the cell B[row][col]. Does that make sense? Also it'll be good to make sure you don't get any index out of bounds exceptions doing this.

Answer (score 0):

This does somewhat depend on the tool/language you are using, for instance matlab starts indexing arrays at 1 so the first element of an array a is `a[1]` while languages like C/Java start indexing at 0 so the first element of an array a is `a[0]`.

Lets assume that indexing is done like in C/Java, then consider a multidimensional array B

```
12 13 14 11
41 17 23 22
18 10 20 38
81 17 32 61
```

Then with `row = 2` and `col = 3` you will have that `B[row][col]` as the element that sits on the third row (remembering indexing starts at 0, so `B[2]` is the third row) and fourth column, marked here between * signs.

```
12 13 14 11
41 17 23 22
18 10 20 *38*
81 17 32 61
```

As for changing a value in the multidimensional array, it is done by assigning a new value to the index of the old value.

```
B[row][col] = B[row+1][col+1] + B[row][col+1];
```

With `row=1` and `col=0` we get

```
B[1][0] = B[2][1] + B[1][1];
B[1][0] = 10 + 17;
B[0][0] = 27;
```

Or:

```
 12 13 14 11               12 13 14 11
(41) 17 23 22              (27) 17 23 22
 18 10 20 38        ==>    18 10 20 38
 81 17 32 61               81 17 32 61
```